# Automatically creating and filling data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, data-structures, plyr

Here is the code that I am working with.

```
  rnumbers <- data.frame(replicate(5,runif(20000, 0, 1)))
dt <- c(.001)
A <- dt*1
B <- dt*.5

## A = 0
## B = 1 

rstate <- rnumbers  # copy the structure
rstate[] <- NA      # preserve structure with NA's
# Init:
rstate[1, ] <- rnumbers[1, ] <  .02 & rnumbers[1, ] > 0.01

step_generator <- function(col, rnum){
    for (i in 2:length(col) ){
            if( rnum[i] < B) { col[i] <- 0  }
                       else { if (rnum[i] < A) {col[i] <- 1 }
                              else {col[i] <- col[i-1] } }
                        }
    return(col)
    }
#  Run for each column index:
for(cl in 1:5){ rstate[ , cl] <- 
                        step_generator(rstate[,cl], rnumbers[,cl]) }



rstate1 <- transform(rstate, time = rep(dt))
rstate2 <- transform(rstate1, cumtime = cumsum(time))
```

This gives me a data frame with 5 columns that contain state switches over time. Time interval is in the 6th column (seconds) and cumulative time is in the 7th column (seconds). Now I want to see how long each state lasts in seconds. This is what I am doing -

1) `lengths <- rle(rstate2[,1])`

```
>Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:15] 366 3278 1817 451 3033 1655 1901 748 742 1780 ...
  values : num [1:15] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...
```

2) `lengths1 <- data.frame(state = lengths$values, duration = lengths$lengths)`

```
> lengths1
       state duration
    1      0      366
    2      1     3278
    3      0     1817
    4      1      451
    5      0     3033
    6      1     1655
    7      0     1901
    8      1      748
    9      0      742
    10     1     1780
    11     0       26
    12     1      458
    13     0      305
    14     1     1039
    15     0     2401
```

3) `library("plyr")`

```
lengths2 <- transform(lengths1, time = duration*dt)
lengths3 <- arrange(lengths2, desc(state))

> lengths3
   state duration  time
1      1     3278 3.278
2      1      451 0.451
3      1     1655 1.655
4      1      748 0.748
5      1     1780 1.780
6      1      458 0.458
7      1     1039 1.039
8      0      366 0.366
9      0     1817 1.817
10     0     3033 3.033
11     0     1901 1.901
12     0      742 0.742
13     0       26 0.026
14     0      305 0.305
15     0     2401 2.401
```

4) `col1 <- ddply(lengths3, .(state), function(df) 1/mean(df$time))`

```
> col1
  state        V1
1     0 0.7553583
2     1 0.7439685
```

So, col1 is showing me "1/mean(time in each state)" for column1 of `rstate2`. What I would like to do is iterate steps 1-4 for every column in `rstate2` and generate a data frame that looks like this :

```
> rates
  state col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1     0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5
2     1  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
```

Where the numbers for each column are  equal to the `1/mean(df$time)` for each of the column from rstate2.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this using the development version of `data.table` ([v 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240)) in this manner:

```
require(data.table) # 1.8.11
require(reshape2)
DT <- data.table(rstate2)
DT.m <- melt(DT, id=6, measure=1:5)
ans <- DT.m[, {dl=data.table:::duplist(list(value)); 
               list(state=value[dl], time=c(diff(dl), 
               .N-dl[length(dl)]+1)*dt)
              }, by=list(variable)]
ans <- ans[, 1/mean(time), by=list(variable, state)]
dcast.data.table(ans, state ~ variable)

   state        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5
1:     0 0.9875568 1.0777521 0.3227194 2.2371365 0.7237054
2:     1 1.0127608 0.4442799 0.2802691 0.2887169 1.0576415
```

Unfortunately, it's still building on R-Forge. So, probably you can install 1.8.10 from CRAN and use `reshape2`'s melt and cast (which'll output a data.frame) and convert the result back to a data.table and do the grouping as follows:

```
require(data.table) # 1.8.10
require(reshape2)
DT.m <- data.table(melt(rstate2, id=6, measure=1:5))
ans <- DT.m[, {dl=data.table:::duplist(list(value)); 
               list(state=value[dl], time=c(diff(dl), 
               .N-dl[length(dl)]+1)*dt)
              }, by=list(variable)]
ans <- ans[, 1/mean(time), by=list(variable, state)]
dcast(ans, state ~ variable)
```